# Как закрыть страницу UWP Mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

Как закрыть программно страницу, или просто вернуться назад, сэмулировав клавишу Back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В code-behind страницы написать:

```
if (Frame.CanGoBack)
{
    Frame.GoBack();
}
```